# Post JSON to PHP and then trigger a file download from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, download

I'm thinking about a webpage that posts json object to a PHP page, and then the PHP page generates some  data and exports the data to a local file. Because in the first step, the data will be too large to pass through URL, I need to use JSON. However, when I passed the JSON object to PHP in an AJAX way, no downloading is triggered. I'm wondering how this downloading can be triggered.

```
//the code will not trigger a download from PHP
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("POST", "export.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I can receive the echoed data in JavaScript, but creating local files in JavaScript is more complex than in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: create a form and use JavaScript to dynamically create hidden input fields. And use a submit button to post the form to the php file in a newly opened window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `xmlhttprequest`, just submit the form with your json to PHP and in PHP specify the correct `Content-Type`.

Comment: But that's not what I meant. I'm not submitting a form to php, but pass a large amount of data (longer than URL can carry) to php and then expect a file downloading from the php code. For example, an user can choose some rows from a database table on the webpage, and then click a button called 'export selected rows to file' to trigger a download.

Comment: You are sending the HTTP POST request, the same thing that form does. You don't need to add it to HTML you can submit it from JS so it is still 'hidden' from the user. I don't think that you can do this the way you wanted. You will probably need to spawn a new tab or change the location in javascript for browser to display download properly.